# live server in vs code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I am new to web development and I installed vs code for understanding html .
as I installed extension live server I and write an html file then when I clicked on  go live for preview of my html code in web browser but my browser doesn't opened and only port 5500 was written in place of go live with a pop up showing ( server is started but failed to show browser preview ) , so what should i do so that my html code can be seen on browser when I click on go live ? help me out I am new to web development and I am understanding it from online tutorials

Answer (score 0):

After clicking on go live, you can go to `localhost:5500` to view the live preview.

Answer (score 0):

Press CTRL + SHIFT + P and search for "Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)". After the last entry, add a new one (Don't forget to add a comma):

```
"liveServer.settings.useBrowserPreview": false
```

You also have to add a comma at the entry before.
Another approach would be to install the [Browser Preview](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=auchenberg.vscode-browser-preview&ssr=false#overview) Extension.